# Filter pipe throws an error that data is undefined when data is returned from a service

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6 and  I built a custom filter pipe. When I was using this with static data it was working fine but when I am getting the data from a service it throws an error "Cannot read property toLowerCase of null. Below is my code.

The model I am using

```
export class Page {
pageID: number;
pageName: string;
module: string;
incomingEEP: string;
outgoingEEP: string;
}
```

The service I created

```
export class PageService {
urlString = 'localhost/8080/db/Page';
private pages: Page[] = [];
public pageUpdate = new Subject<Page[]>();

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

public getPage() {
this.httpClient.get<Page>(this.urlString).subscribe(data => {
this.pages = data;
this.pageUpdate.next([...this.pages]);
});
}

public pageUpdateListener() {
retirn this.pageUpdate.asObservable();
}
```

This is my component

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
pages: Page[];
search = '';
pageSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private pageService: PageService) {}
ngOnInit() {
this.pageService.getPage();
this.pageSubscription = this.pageService.pageUpdateListener().subscribe(data => {
this.pages = data;
}
}
}
```

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "search">
<clr-datagrid>
<clr-dg-column>Page</clr-dg-column>
<clr-dg-column>Module</clr-dg-column>
<clr-dg-column>Incoming EEP</clr-dg-column>
<clr-dg-column>Outgoing EEP</clr-dg-column>

<clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let page of pages | filter:search" [clrDgItem]="page">
<clr-dg-cell>page.pageName</clr-dg-cell>
clr-dg-cell>page.module</clr-dg-cell>
clr-dg-cell>page.incomingEEP</clr-dg-cell>
clr-dg-cell>page.outgoingEEP</clr-dg-cell>
</clr-dg-row>
</clr-datagrid>
```

Lastly here is my filter.

```
@Pipe({
name: 'filter',
pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], search: string): any[] {
if (!items) return [];
if (!search) return items;

search = search.toLowerCase();

return items.filter(page => {
return page.pageName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0
|| page.module.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0
|| page.incomingEEP.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0
|| page.outgoingEEP.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the async pipe

```
pages$ = this.pageService.pageUpdateListener();
```

and in the view

```
<clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let page of (pages$ | async | filter:search)" [clrDgItem]="page">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am still getting the same error.